# d3js - Force-Directed Graph: Delete node that only link to itself

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, force-layout

I am trying to do the Force-Directed Graph from [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) but my data is really big (5000 nodes) so I want to remove some nodes that do not link to any other nodes.

However, in my JSON, every node has at least 1 link  (that link to itself). This is an example of my data:

```
{"directed": false, "graph": {}, 
"nodes": [{"id": 0}, {"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 3}, {"id": 4}, {"id": 5}, 
         {"id": 6}, {"id": 7}, {"id": 8}, {"id": 9}, {"id": 10}, {"id": 11}, {"id": 12}], 

"links": [{"source": 0, "target": 0}, {"source": 1, "target": 1}, 
    {"source": 2, "target": 2}, {"source": 3, "target": 3}, 
    {"source": 4, "target": 4}, {"source": 5, "target": 5}, 
    {"source": 6, "target": 6}, {"source": 7, "target": 8}, 
    {"source": 7, "target": 9}, {"source": 7, "target": 10}, 
    {"source": 7, "target": 11}, {"source": 7, "target": 7}, 
    {"source": 8, "target": 8}, {"source": 9, "target": 9}, 
    {"source": 10, "target": 10}, {"source": 11, "target": 11}, 
    {"source": 12, "target": 12}], "multigraph": false}
```

I.e., node `id:0` only has link `{"source": 0, "target": 0}` so it should get removed but node `id:7` has links `{"source": 7, "target": 8}, {"source": 7, "target": 7}`. It is linked to another node so it should not get removed.

My question is how do I delete nodes that only link to itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to first boil down the links to those which are not referring to the same node, i.e. where `source !== target`. I chose to use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) although other ways of iteration will work just the same. To speed up the elimintation of nodes later on I am also employing a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to store *unique* id values, which technically is not necessary for this to work, though.

```
let uniqueNonSelfReferringLinks = data.links.reduce((set, {source:s, target:t}) =>
  s !== t ? set.add(s).add(t) : set,
  new Set()
);
```

Filtering the nodes then comes down to iterating the `nodes` array looking up the set for the value of the nodes' ids:

```
let filteredNodes = data.nodes.filter(n => uniqueNonSelfReferringLinks.has(n.id));
```

Consolidating both steps into one this can be written even more concisely:

```
let filteredNodes = data.nodes.filter(
  function(n) { return this.has(n.id); },  
  data.links.reduce((set, {source:s, target:t}) =>
    s !== t ? set.add(s).add(t) : set,
    new Set()
  )
);
```

Have a look at the following working demo:

```js
var data = {
  "directed": false,
  "graph": {}, 
  "nodes": [{"id": 0}, {"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 3}, {"id": 4}, {"id": 5}, 
         {"id": 6}, {"id": 7}, {"id": 8}, {"id": 9}, {"id": 10}, {"id": 11}, {"id": 12}], 

  "links": [{"source": 0, "target": 0}, {"source": 1, "target": 1}, 
    {"source": 2, "target": 2}, {"source": 3, "target": 3}, 
    {"source": 4, "target": 4}, {"source": 5, "target": 5}, 
    {"source": 6, "target": 6}, {"source": 7, "target": 8}, 
    {"source": 7, "target": 9}, {"source": 7, "target": 10}, 
    {"source": 7, "target": 11}, {"source": 7, "target": 7}, 
    {"source": 8, "target": 8}, {"source": 9, "target": 9}, 
    {"source": 10, "target": 10}, {"source": 11, "target": 11}, 
    {"source": 12, "target": 12}],
  "multigraph": false
};

let filteredNodes = data.nodes.filter(
  function(n) { return this.has(n.id); },  
  data.links.reduce((set, {source:s, target:t}) =>
    s !== t ? set.add(s).add(t) : set,
    new Set()
  )
);

console.log(filteredNodes);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's work really well. I have one more question though.

When I open my graph in browser it's still really laggy. Is there a way to improve the performace? my code were like the example (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045)

Comment: Just to quote your comment: *"I have one more question though."* Please post it as such; that issue is well worth its own question which should come along with a working demo showing the problem! But, before putting too much effort into this, I suggest you have a look at [*"d3js force large number of nodes"*](/q/22318673) and read the first sentence of the accepted answer out loudly five times in a row ;-) If you still feel the need to depict your data, read the rest of the post, and then, maybe, write your new question.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for the help.