# D3js Force-Directed Graph - Remove the animation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, force-layout

I am trying to working with [this force-directed graph](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045). Right now I am able to write the graph fine but since my graph have 2000 nodes its feel very laggy. So I decide to remove the starting animation but still can't find a way to do that. I already look at [Static Force Layout](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667139) and try to work around but it still not working.

Is there a way to remove the animation or there other way to reduce the lag?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.links line {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<svg width="2000" height="1500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));


d3.json("force.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;

  // Taken from related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44113223/4235784
  let filteredNodes = graph.nodes.filter(
    function(n) { return this.has(n.id); },  
    graph.links.reduce((set, {source:s, target:t}) =>
      s !== t ? set.add(s).add(t) : set,
      new Set()
    )
  );

  var link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
      .selectAll("line")
      .data(graph.links)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(filteredNodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); });

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }
});



</script>
```

Comment: Have you read the text accompanying the *Static Force Layout* you linked to? *"To avoid freezing the user interface, it may be desirable to compute the force-directed layout in a web worker."* That even links to the working [*Force-Directed Web Worker*](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/01ab2e85e8727d6529d20391c0fd9a16) example.

Comment: Yes, I already look at that link but I didn't understand it. I am still new to these stuff.